# Why is this not a function

Tags: typescript, aurelia

For some reason `authenticationProvider` seems to be missing.

```
@autoinject()
export class ProviderManager implements AuthenticationManager {
   constructor( private container: Container ){
   }
    public authenticate( creds: Credentials ): Promise<Authentication> {
        var provider = creds.authenticationProvider();
        return this.container.get( provider ).authenticate( creds );
    }

}
```

`Credentials`

```
export interface Credentials {
    authenticationProvider(): { new(): AuthenticationManager };
}
```

the implementation `UsernamePasswordCredentials`

```
export class UsernamePasswordCredentials implements Credentials {

    public authenticationProvider(): {new(): AuthenticationManager} {
        return HttpBasicAuthentication;
    }

    user: String;
    pass: String;
}
```

`AuthenticationManager`

```
export interface AuthenticationManager {
    authenticate( creds: Credentials ): Promise<Authentication>;
}
```

`Login`

```
@autoinject()
export class Login {
    private log: Logger = LogManager.getLogger( Login );
    creds: UsernamePasswordCredentials;

    constructor( private am: AuthenticationManager, private router: Router ) {
    }

    public signIn(): void {
        this.log.debug( `authenticating ${ this.creds.user }` );
        this.am.authenticate( this.creds ).then( auth => {
            var route = Route.MANAGE_CONTENT;
            this.log.debug( `navigating to ${ route }` );
            var router = this.router;
            router.navigate( route );
        } ).catch( error => {
            this.log.error( error );
        } );
    }
}
```

Here's Chrome's stacktrace

```
   VM802:1 Uncaught TypeError: creds.authenticationProvider is not a function(…)(anonymous function) @ VM802:1
authenticate @ ProviderManager.ts:13
signIn @ login.ts:22evaluate @ aurelia-binding.js:1522
callSource @ aurelia-binding.js:4963
(anonymous function) @ aurelia-binding.js:4987
handleDelegatedEvent @ aurelia-binding.js:3176
```

Comment: In your signIn method (login.ts:22), what do you pass into the `providerManager.authenticate` method? Is there any chance it's not been initialised properly or isn't an instance of UsernamePasswordCredentials at runtime?

Comment: @DavidE added `Login` TS, but you're somehow basically right... I'm not sure I fully understand what's going on, the reference isn't null and the binding works. adding `creds: UsernamePasswordCredentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials;` causes it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the `Login` code.

You're on the right lines, but it appears that `this.creds` was previously undefined.

The code

```
class Login {
    creds: UsernamePasswordCredentials;
}
```

just tells Typescript that it expect creds to be of type `UsernamePasswordCredentials`. But it does nothing to initialize the creds field... in particular, no javascript will get emitted for the line when the above gets transpiled (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ might be helpful to look at what the transpiler does).

That means that, in the `signIn` method, `this.creds` will be undefined.

This is similar to, say, in C#, where if you don't initialize a field, it defaults to `null`.

Whilst Typescript can catch a lot of things, it cannot (always) catch when a variable has an undefined/null value at run-time, just as a statically typed language like C# can still end up generating compiled code which triggers null reference exceptions.

EDIT: Ahh, my apologies. Had `creds` been undefined, you would have received a `ReferenceError: creds is not defined`. The `TypeError` should have made clear `creds` was populated elsewhere, but of the wrong type.

Comment: well that's sort of true see, aurelia is populating user/pass with databinding... but my guess is since this happens at runtime... it's simply creating a new javascript object without the types... and is unaware of the extra method.

Comment: Is it populating creds with an object of instance `UsernamePasswordCredentials` ? Or just an object of type `{ user: string, pass: string }`?

Comment: Chrome says `Object` that has getters and setters like I defined in UsernamePasswordCredentials ... so that's extra confusing (maybe has something to do with aurelia binding though), it serializes to basically just the properties.

Comment: Also, are you sure the data binding happens before `signIn` is called? Setting an initializer to `creds: UsernamePasswordCredentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials` making it work suggests that aurelia hasn't replaced it?

Maybe the most likely possibility is aurelia just sets `creds.user` and `creds.pass` but doesn't replace the `creds` object binding...

Comment: Ahh that does sound rather weird. I don't know enough about aurelia to be of much further help to be honest. But glad you've got some ideas of how to fix it. Good luck!

Comment: s'all good, lot of framework magic making it extra confusing, but simplified it really is because I didn't call new.

I've seen a similar sort of improper type casting that incidentally worked, in a Spring 3 -> 4 conversion, where Spring 4 caught the error.

Comment: the type does not show as `Object`, when I use `new UsernamePasswordCredentials`